# Add vertical scrollbar for code block in html document generated from a quarto markdown file

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, quarto

I would like code blocks to have a vertical scrollbar in html files generated from qmd files.

I couldn't figure it out.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Test format"
format: 
  html:
    code-overflow: scroll
    embed-resources: true
---


```{css, echo=FALSE}
pre {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

pre[class] {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```


```{r}
x = 1 + 1

#
#


head (mtcars)     ############################################################################################################################################
```
````

I tried to render this (as .qmd file) in Rstudio (version 2023.06.1) and:

- there is no vertical scrollbar for the code block
- there is a vertical scrollbar for the code output